# Checking later the state of nodes during a past job execution

Tags: azure-batch

Is there a way to check in Azure Batch whether a node went to the unusable state while running a specific job on a specific pool? The context is that, when running a job and checking the pool on which it was running at that time, there were some nodes that went to the unusable state during the job execution, but we wouldn't have any indication that this happened if we weren't checking the heatmap of the pool during the job execution. Thus, **how can I check if nodes went to the unusable state during some job run**?

Also, I see that there are metrics collected about the state of nodes in Azure portal, but I am not sure why these metrics are always zero for me even though I am running jobs and tasks that fail?

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look for you: (I hope this helps `:)`)

For the nodes state monitoring you can do something mentioned here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-efficient-list-queries
- PoolOperations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.pooloperations?view=azurebatch-7.0.1

  - [ListComputeNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.pooloperations.listcomputenodes?view=azurebatch-7.0.1#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_PoolOperations_ListComputeNodes_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Batch_DetailLevel_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_Azure_Batch_BatchClientBehavior__) : Enumerates the ComputeNode of the specified pool.
  - I think at the detail level if you filter with correct clasue you will get ComputeNode information, then you can loop through the information and check the state.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.common.computenodestate?view=azurebatch-7.0.1
- Possible sample implementation: (Please note this specific code is probably for the pool health) https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/CSharp/Common/GettingStartedCommon.cs#L31

With regards to the metrics, how are you getting the metrics back. I am sure I will get corrected if I said anything doubtful or incorrect. Thanks!